# How to remove Crosswalk from a Cordova project?

Tags: android, cordova, crosswalk-runtime

I have added Crosswalk to a cordova project, it works ok.
But I wanted to remove it to do some tests, but I can't find out how.

I tried to remove the following line

```
android.library.reference.2=org.apache.cordova.engine.crosswalk/xwalk_core_library
```

from the project.properties file but the build process crashes.

Any help? Didn't find it in the documentation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I am working with Ionic these days, which I guess it's the same case. Give this a try:

```
$ cordova browser revert android
# or
$ cordova browser remove crosswalk
```

Comment: Actually it's: ionic browser remove crosswalk if you use Ionic.

Comment: Sure, but the question is about a Cordova project. Could be something else from Ionic.

Comment: Do you guys know why I get "package could be damaged" whilte trying to upgrade from Crosswalk app version to newer non-Crosswalk app version?

Answer (score 28):

```
$ cordova plugin remove crosswalk-webview
```

is what worked for me

i also had to comment out the below line in platforms/android/project.properties

```
cordova.gradle.include.1=cordova-plugin-crosswalk-webview/v1-xwalk.gradle
```

Comment: In my case it was `cordova plugin remove cordova-plugin-crosswalk-webview`; I also had to manually remove a folder with the same name from `./platforms/android/`.

Answer (score 1):

for ionic 4.x i used it

```
ionic cordova plugin remove crosswalk-webview
```

Answer (score 0):

to remove crosswalk for new versions of cordova or ionic please try the following

```
$ cordova plugin remove crosswalk-webview
```

and then

```
$ cordova platform remove android 
$ cordova platform add android
```